# Java OptionalDataException when only serializing objects (no primitive data types anywhere)

Tags: java, serialization, optionaldataexception

I'm dealing with a strange OptionalDataException that I can't figure out.

I have objects coming in, which are saved to disk by a class that write them by decorating an `OutputObjectStream` and calling its `writeUnshared` method. Periodically, every 10000 objects, it calls `flush` and `reset`. Finally, it closes the stream.

This way, I create a small number of files that only contain serialized objects.

Here's the thing. After all those files are written, I take a pair and try to mergesort them. At this point, size of the files hasn't changed (as expected).

To do this, I start by opening two streams and calling `readObject` on each one.

However, this call to `readObject` (the first one on each stream) throws `OptionalDataException`, everytime with `eof = false, length = 4`, which as I understand indicates that I'm reading a primitive data type, or something else is happening that I'm not getting.

Answer (score 0):

OK, need to share this.

I had created a wrapper for an ObjectOutputStream, that as I said, counted the amount of serialized objects in order to call `reset` periodically.

The problem was in the constructor of that class, which basically was:

```
class CustomObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    private int flushBoundary;

    CustomObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream oos, int flushLimit){
               super(oos);
               ...
     }
   //other methods
}
```

Now, a closer look to [the javadoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream)) says that

> Creates an ObjectOutputStream that writes to the specified
> OutputStream. This constructor writes the serialization stream header
> to the underlying stream; callers may wish to flush the stream
> immediately to ensure that constructors for receiving
> ObjectInputStreams will not block when reading the header.

Meaning that there was "some extra stuff" at the beggining of the file. I changed the super() call to the default one, and the OptionalDataExceptions dissapeared.

Comment: Why are you using an `ObjectOutputStream` as a delegate when you are already inheriting from it? The parameter should be `OutputStream,` and it should *not* be an `ObjectOutputStream.` And you should be calling `super(os,...).`

Comment: It's tech. debt. Will be changed in the near future. Whats with the ldots in the `super` call?

Comment: Tech debt? Idiots? What are you talking about?